# Can somebody explain me the following LINQ code?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble interpreting code from someone else.

I know the behavior, but I don't understand how.
Behavior:

- `driverRemark` has a sequence number and can be linked to a group.
  The group that contains the remark with the lowest seq nr should be printed out first. and so on.
  If 2 remarks have the lowest seq nr, the lowest group should be printed first. except when its null, null should be printed last.

Can somebody explain me what is happening here?

```
 var groupedDriverRemarks = driverRemarks
                .GroupBy(dr => dr.RemarkGroup)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key == null)
                .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                .OrderBy(gr => gr.Min(dr => dr.SeqNr))
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(dr => dr.SeqNr))
                .ToList();

 return groupedDriverRemarks;
```

I have no clue how this function operates. It does work, but no clue why.

I tried searching all the different LINQ methods and try to translate it. But without any result.

Comment: What would you like to know about it. Those LINQ functions are pretty self-descriptive! If you are using Entity Framework, those functions will be translated to SQL.

Comment: That's a *very* convoluted way of ordering by two different fields. I doubt if this can be translated to SQL at all. It's already way too expensive running this against an in-memory collection

Comment: @Transcendent quite the opposite, this code is overcomplicate and even if this could be translated to SQL, it would be *very* expensive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: If you mean it can be optimized then it's another story. But to me it's not complicated, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Transcendent care to explain then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The guy who posted the answer already did that!

Comment: Can you try `driverRemarks.OrderBy(dr=>new {dr.SeqNr,dr.RemarkGroup,SeqNr}).Select(dr=>dr.RemarkGroup).Take(1);` ?

Comment: @Transcendent you mean ChatGPT? No it didn't, it just copied the method definitions without actually explaining how anything works or why

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: wow that's crazy. ChatGPT is getting scary.

Comment: @Transcendent no, every single ChatGPT answer is as bad as that if not worse. The fluff looks nice but there's 0 understanding of the question. When code is included, it often includes non-existent methods and types that match the blurb. Other times, the code contradicts the blurb

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I haven't used ChatGPT yet. I have only seen videos. That's why I couldn't tell the answer is from that system.

Comment: To order `null` last *in LINQ-to-Objects*, you can use `new {dr.SeqNr, dr.RemarkGroup.SeqNr ?? int.MaxValue}` or the equivalent for `SeqNr`'s type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for clarifying: maybe one more question:
.OrderBy(gr => gr.Min(dr => dr.SeqNr))

This means taking into account all the groups, order the groups ascending with the seq number?

Comment: No, it means order by the minimum seq number in the group. Something you wouldn't have to do if you were ordering the remarks from the start. There's only one group per remark after all, which is available through `dr.RemarkGroup`.

Comment: This query returns all remarks though. `g.Key == null` is used to convert `Key` into a True/False value that would cause `NULL`s to become true and thus the last value when sorting in ascending order. `SelectMany` *ungroups* the remarks.

Comment: This code looks like an attempt to literally translate the problem description into code without understanding what the description says. Why use `OrderBy().Then()` when you can write `.OrderBy(row=>new {row.Prop1,row.Prop2})` for example?

Comment: @Transcendent notice Matthew Watson's comment. In this case ChatGPT modified the blurb to fit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a commented version of the code:

```
var groupedDriverRemarks = driverRemarks
                .GroupBy(dr => dr.RemarkGroup) // group driver remarks by RemarkGroup
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key == null) // order groups so null RemarkGroup is last
                .ThenBy(g => g.Key) // order non-null remark groups by RemarkGroup
                .OrderBy(gr => gr.Min(dr => dr.SeqNr))
                // re-order remark groups by minimum of SeqNr; 
                // since previous ordering is preserved, any duplicate minimum SeqNr will be ordered by RemarkGroup with null last still
                .SelectMany(
                    g => g.OrderBy(dr => dr.SeqNr) // sort contents of each group in SeqNr order
                ) // flatten SeqNr sorted groups into single stream
                .ToList(); // convert ordered driver remarks to a List<T>
```

The use of multiple sorts is not an efficient way to handle sub-sorts, the `ThenBy` method is intended for this, so you have one sort that works correctly. Here is an improved version; it uses one sort before grouping to pre-order all the driver remarks so the final result is properly sorted after grouping.

```
var orderedDriverRemarks =
    driverRemarks
        .OrderBy(dr => dr.SeqNr) // order the driver remarks by SeqNr
        .OrderBy(dr => dr.RemarkGroup == null) // then order duplicate SeqNr so the null RemarkGroup remarks are last
        .ThenBy(dr => dr.RemarkGroup) // then order by RemarkGroup for the non-null remarks with duplicate SeqNr
        .GroupBy(dr => dr.RemarkGroup) // group driver remarks by RemarkGroup
        // since GroupBy is order preserving, the groups will be ordered by their first SeqNr
        // which is the minimum SeqNr in each group, then duplicate min SeqNrs will be ordered
        // by RemarkGroup with null last
        // in addition, the contents of each group will be ordered by SeqNr
        .SelectMany(g => g) // flatten groups into single stream
        .ToList(); // convert ordered driver remarks to a List<T>
```